# Symfony 4.1 - Can't inject dependencies in custom Form base class

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I have a service with id `manager_provider` and I would like to create a base form class called `ManagerAwareType` with this service injected. Therefore all form classes extending this one would have access to `manager_provider`:

```
abstract class ManagerAwareType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ManagerProvider */
    private $managerProvider;

    // getter and setter...
}
```

So my first try was to declare this using `_instanceof` in `services.yaml`:

```
_instanceof:
    MyBundle\Form\ManagerAwareType:
      tags: [form.type]
      calls:
        - [setManagerProvider, ["@manager_provider"]]
```

but when I create the form in Controller `$managerProvider` is `null`. Then I tried to do the same programatically in a `DependencyInjection\Extension` class and the code is being executed without any error (checked with debugger):

```
$managerAwareType = new Definition(ManagerAwareType::class);
$managerAwareType->addTag('form.type');
$managerAwareType->addMethodCall('setManagerProvider', [new Definition('manager_provider')]);
$container->addDefinitions([$managerAwareType]);
```

but again it didn't work, the dependency is not injected.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I know I could declare my dependency as form option and inject it each time I create the form through the Controller but I prefer this way if possible.

Comment: Not positive but you might need to use the container's parent capability: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually tell your `ManagerAwareType` class about class you want to inject. Usual way is to put it in the __construct function:

```
abstract class ManagerAwareType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ManagerProvider */
    private $managerProvider;

    public function __construct(ManagerProvider $mp)
    {
        $this->managerProvider = $mp
    }

    // getter and setter...
}
```